# SQL LEFT JOIN distributive?

Tags: mysql, sql

Distributive, in the mathematical sense is the property of:

```
f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)
```

Now I have this SQL Script, which in general looks like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN (
    Subquery_A
    UNION ALL
    Subquery_B
    UNION ALL
    ...
    UNION ALL Subquery_Z
)
```

Is the query **mathematically distributive**?

That is, can I decompose it to

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN (Subquery_A)
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN (Subquery_B)
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN (Subquery_Z)
```

The reason I'm asking this is that I have a HUGE query (13'000+ lines) that more often than not exceeds the maximum connection lifetime of a corporate database. However, reducing the query to just 1 subquery works and fall well within the maximum connection lifetime.

So, I had the idea of splitting that huge query into many individual queries and perform the `UNION ALL` on the client side. (Because UNION ALL is after a simple joining of the result of the subqueries)

Do you think this will work?

Comment: Yes, it should work but it won't be faster..

Comment: No, it's not completely the same because each of the subqueries would have a complete list of records from the table on the left hand side. You have to eliminate the multiple records where there is no match to the record in the left hand side table in any of the subqueries.

Comment: @sagi yes, *total* time might be slower, but at least each component now finishes faster. As it is now, due to the massive amount of processing, the humongous query more often than not fails due to timeout. If I decompose the humongous query, each individual decomposition would finish without timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not completely the same because each of the subqueries would have a complete list of records from the table on the left hand side. You have to eliminate the multiple records where there is no match to the record in the left hand side table in any of the subqueries.

Let's suppose you have the following values in table1 (left-hand-side table):

```
ID
--
1
2
3
4
5
```

Let's suppose you have the following values returned by 2 subqueries

```
Subquer1ID
--------
1
2

Subquer2ID
--------
1
3
4
```

With the first version of the sql you will get

```
ID  SubquerID   FromSubquery
--  ----------  ----------
1   1           Subquer1
1   1           Subquer2
2   2           Subquer1
3   3           Subquer2
4   4           Subquer2
5   Null        Null
```

With the 2nd version the resultset would be

```
ID  SubquerID   FromSubquery
--  ----------  ----------
1   1           Subquer1
2   2           Subquer1
3   Null        Null
4   Null        Null
5   Null        Null
1   1           Subquer2
2   Null        Null
3   3           Subquer2
4   4           Subquer2
5   Null        Null
```

1. You have to remove the duplicate `ID - Null - Null` rows
2. If you have a row in the result with `ID - Non-null - Non-null` and `Same Id - Null - Null` rows, then the latter ones have to be removed as well.

It would be a lot easier to have a series of `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN (Subquery_A)` queries, then a single `SELECT ... FROM left_hand_side_table` statement and combine the results of the last query with the results from the series of the inner joins, so that any record not in the inner joins are placed in the final resultset.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Yeah I forgot about the case where there were no match but the left side got selected anyways. And thanks for the `INNER JOIN` + `SELECT Left` solution!